# Word (2010): There is insufficient memory or disk space. Word cannot display the requested font

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

My wife's laptop is a MacBook Pro running Windows 7 under BootCamp. It's a fast machine but when she tries to open an existing Word document or make a new blank one she gets the error message "There is insufficient memory or disk space. Word cannot display the requested font" and some of the layout is garbled. As you can see from this screenshot less than half of the 2.16 of usable RAM is in use and 180GB of the 232GB of hard drive are free. Word should **not** be running out of memory at all.

[image: Screenshot showing Word error, task manager, and free disk space]

I have tried

1. Deleting the normal template
2. Disabling all add ons and ins

None of these work. What is going on and how should I fix it?

Comment: Did you recently install any adobe product before this error start showing?

Comment: This message most likely originates from GDI, which calls at least every other error “out of memory”. It’s mostly corrupted data, in this case probably the font file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not work out what was wrong with the installation but

1. Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features
2. Select Microsoft Office 2010 from the list
3. Click 'change'
4. Choose 'repair'

fixed it

Comment: It sounds like a broken install, well done for fixing it. You can accept your own answer as it solved your problem.

Comment: One cannot accept one's own answer for two days, so I've another day to wait. But don't worry I do intend to accept it.

Comment: Has been definitely more than 2 days :)

Answer (score 0):

First try this

Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features

Select Microsoft Office 2010 from the list

Click 'change'

Choose 'repair'

or this ->
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bK06yCpJTho

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it solved the problem.

1. Removed the file "Normal.dotm" in %APPDATA%/Microsoft/Templates
2. Rebooted and open MS Word again

More information in Windows forum: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/insufficient-memory-or-disk-space-cannot-display/e9a40c16-40cd-4fc7-84c0-8382cae47b7f

Answer (score 0):

We recently encountered this with Word 2013 when trying to open Japanese Language documents.

After extensive attempts to manually and thoroughly uninstall/reinstall I finally found that installing the Language Pack seemed to resolve the issue.

I hope that might help someone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

It,s mostly happen when you are upgrading your MS office so if anyone facing this problem any one should reinstall saprately and then resart system ok.

Answer (score 0):

For me running a new word process with the command line switch /n managed to open a fresh word instance that could open and save big documents again.

Answer (score -1):

I did the "go back" or "reset" feature to reset my computer back to before it stated showing this message. It worked for me.

Comment: Not a good answer unless you can explain why it worked.